# Crop video in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to crop a video in HTML 5.

```
<video id="glass" width="640" height="360" autoplay>
    <source src="invisible-glass-fill.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The resolution of the video is 640x360, but when I set the `width` attribute to 200, the video will rescale (retain the aspect ratio). How to crop the video (cut off, say, 220 pixels from both the left and right side) through HTML or Javascript? Is it even possible without cropping the video through video editing software?

Comment: You tried setting `height:auto` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would recommend you to do it with CSS and a wrapper:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
    <video id="glass" width="640" height="360" autoplay>
        <source src="invisible-glass-fill.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 360px;
}

#glass {
    margin-left: -220px;
}
```

Comment: We must define an extra CSS rule to shift the video to the left, in order to make sure that the video is cropped on both sides. We can do it like this: `div.container video { margin-left: -220px; }`. However, this answer led me to the solution.

Comment: @MCEmperor yeah you are right. I forgot about that requisite. Nice to know it helped. I'm gonna update the answer with your contribution.

Comment: Notice that you will need to set the `margin-left` property of the `video` tag inside the `div.container` instead of the `margin-left` property of `div.container` itself. You need to edit your answer. `div.container video { margin-left: -220px; }`

Comment: @MCEmperor my mistake :) Done.

Comment: I used `position: relative; left: -220px` on my `video` element . I don't know if it's better or worse than the negative margin, but it works.

Comment: This is great, thanks. If the '#glass' element is full-screened, cropping is lost. I'm trying to come up with a solution for that...

Comment: There are native cropping approaches without needing to add an extra HTML container element, because the video tag itself is already a container.  You just have to set the CSS accordingly for how you want it cropped, and it will crop automatically how you want. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74999070/220325

Answer (score 6):

Try using CSS property:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

As opposed to `Object-fit: contain;` which is the default that you're describing where the video sizes down to fit fully inside the box with no crop and black bars on either top/bottom or left/right.  `object-fit: cover` will cover the whole video box and allow the extra amounts that go outside the box to be cropped off.

In the `cover` mode, you could just set the width/height of the video element as needed like any normal HTML element, and it will crop whatever doesn't fit naturally with a center/center alignment.

```
object-fit: cover;
object-align: center center; /* default, anchor to center of video */
```

If you want to change the alignment, for example to crop towards the top, right, bottom, left etc, just additionally use the `object-position` CSS property.  For example, "cover" `object-fit` with `object-align: top left` would anchor the top left corner in place, cover the whole video box, scale up to cover the player at whatever size it's set to, and crop everything that sticks out beyond the edges on the right or bottom.

```
object-fit: cover; /* cover the whole video box, no black bars */
object-align: top left; /* anchor to top left corner of video */
```

The `object-align` property can also take pixel or percentage values aside from the keywords presets of center, top, bottom, right, left to get more exact with it if needed.

Comment: For anyone coming across this post now, this is a much more modern solution to this problem than the accepted answer, it worked great for me! I've used the `object-fit: cover` property before but I didn't realize it worked properly for video elements, so thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same need (wanting to crop video on the fly instead of cropping the actual video).

My solution is pretty simple, and works so that you don't need to specify the height or width of the container in absolutes, therefore it's responsive. I've just used inline styles here for simplicity, but you can easily move the css to classes etc.

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" style="margin-top: -10.5%; margin-bottom: -10.5%"></video>
</div>
```

In this example I used negative margins in percentages. Keep in mind that using percentages, that they're calculated based on the container's width. So it's not 10.5% of the videos's height. I think you'd need to use javascript if you were wanting to do that. However, with this approach you can also use `vh` or `vw` units. Or do what Alvaro suggested and set widths on the container if you want it to be absolutely sized, and use `px` to set the margins.

Check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/LichenDigital/pen/qBReygN) for more examples!

Comment: This is not a great way to go about this because 1) it requires adding an extra container DIV element which is not necessary, and 2) if the DIV element needs to change on page, goes full screen, etc, the manually keyed in negative margins etc will not work nicely, and you'll end up doing different mobile responsive rules etc.  Just use CSS instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/74999070/220325