# How to crop an embedded video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an embedded .swf animation on my html page. How can I show only the right 50% of it?

*(Preferably without jQuery)*

```
<embed src="includes/annation.swf" style="width:98%; height:95vh; margin-left: 15px;">
```

Comment: using css, try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716077/crop-video-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop video in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716077/crop-video-in-html)